# The prop from another component using navigate is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I would like to pass a prop using navigate. But it keeps giving me undefined.
If I just call the child component, I see the right prop, but not navigate. This is my code below

Parent component

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const componentChange = (username) => {
   navigate('/editproduct/'+{username}, {replace:true})
}

return (
    <button onClick={()=>componentChange(username)}>Edit</button>
)
```

child component

```
function EditProduct(props) {
    console.log(props.username)
    return (
        <div className='p-5'>hello {props.username}</div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `useParam`

```
function EditProduct(props) {
     const { userName } = useParams();
     //     should dbe the same param name define in route. like this
     //     <Route  path="editproduct/:userName" component={App} />


    return (
        <div className='p-5'>hello {props.username}</div>
    )
}
```

Comment: It finally works!!! Super thank you so much